# How to divide slices of a keras 3D tensor with elements of a vector?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to perform a tensor operation where each slice of the tensor is divided by the corresponding element from a vector. For example, a tensor K of shape (4,80,50) have 4 slices of shape(80,50) along the axes-0. Each of the 4 slices have to be divided by elements of the vector P of shape (4,1) ie. K[0,:,:] /p[0] , K[1,:,:]/p[1] etc. Is there a keras function which can perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `K` and `P` have the same size of 0-axis, you need to expand dimension of `P` at the end. In tf2.0, here is an example

```py
K = tf.reshape(tf.range(24),(4,2,3))
#array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4,  5]],
#
#       [[ 6,  7,  8],
#        [ 9, 10, 11]],
#
#       [[12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17]],
#
#       [[18, 19, 20],
#        [21, 22, 23]]])

P = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1,2,4,8]),(4,1))

K / tf.expand_dims(P,axis=-1)
#array([[[0.   , 1.   , 2.   ],
#        [3.   , 4.   , 5.   ]],
#
#       [[3.   , 3.5  , 4.   ],
#        [4.5  , 5.   , 5.5  ]],
#
#       [[3.   , 3.25 , 3.5  ],
#        [3.75 , 4.   , 4.25 ]],
#
#       [[2.25 , 2.375, 2.5  ],
#        [2.625, 2.75 , 2.875]]])
```